# I have a problem : session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: N;C:\xampp\tmp) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sessions\index.php on line 79 array(0)

Tags: php

```php
<?php

    define('SESSION_SAVE_PATH' ,'N;C:\xampp\tmp');
   
    
  class AppSessionHandler extends SessionHandler{
    
    
    
    private $sessionName = 'MYSESSION';
    private $sessionMaxLifeTime = 0 ;
    private $sessionSSl = true ;
    private $seesionHTTPOnly = true ;
    private $sessionPath = '/';
    private $sessionDomain = 'localhost';
    private $sessionSavePath = SESSION_SAVE_PATH ;
    private $key = 'qkwjdiw239jdafwe';
    private $ttl = 1 ;



     public function encrptionThis($data , $key){
          $encryptionKey = base64_decode($key) ;
          $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
          $encrypted =  openssl_encrypt($data ,'aes-256-cbc' , $encryptionKey , 0 , $iv);
          return base64_encode($encrypted.'::'.$iv) ;
      }

      public function decryptionThis($data , $key){

          $encryptionKey = base64_decode($key) ;
          list($encryptedDate ,$iv) = array_pad(explode('::',base64_decode($data) ,2),2,null);
          return openssl_decrypt($encryptedDate,'aes-256-cbc' , $encryptionKey , 0 , $iv) ;
      }

    public function __construct(){

        ini_set('seesion.use_cookies'  ,1 )  ;
        ini_set('seesion.use_only_cookies'  ,1 )  ;
        ini_set('sesssion.use_trans_sid' , 0) ;
        ini_set('session.save_handler' , 'files') ;
        ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);

        session_name($this->sessionName) ;
        session_save_path($this->sessionSavePath) ;
        session_set_cookie_params(
            $this->sessionMaxLifeTime,
            $this->sessionPath,
            $this->sessionDomain,
            $this->sessionSSl ,
            $this->seesionHTTPOnly) ;
        session_set_save_handler($this,true) ;
    }


    public function __get($key)
    {
        // TODO: Implement __get() method.

        return false !== $_SESSION[$key] ? $_SESSION[$key]  : false ;
    }


    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        // TODO: Implement __set() method.
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value ;
    }


    public function __isset($key) {
          return isset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }


      public function start(){
          if('' == session_id()) {
              echo session_id();
               if(session_start()){
                   $this->setSessionStartTime();
                   $this->checkSessionValidity();
                }
          }
      }


      public function write($session_id, $session_data)
      {
          return parent::write($session_id ,$this->encrptionThis($session_data,$this->key));

      }


      public function read($session_id){
            return $this->decryptionThis(parent::read($session_id),$this->key); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        }

        private function setSessionStartTime(){
            if(!isset($this->sessionStartTime)){
                $this-> sessionStartTime = time() ;
            }
            return true;
        }


        private function  checkSessionValidity(){
          if((time() - $this->sessionStartTime) > ($this->ttl*60)){
                $this->renewSession() ;
          }
          return true;
        }


        private function renewSession(){
            $this->sessionStartTime = time() ;
           return session_regenerate_id(true) ;
        }

  }

        $sessionTest = new AppSessionHandler();
        $sessionTest->start();
```

Comment: The code in the question needs proper formatting as i can't understand the code at all

Comment: Https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You may try changing the 1st line to  `define('SESSION_SAVE_PATH' ,'C:\xampp\tmp');` and make sure you have c:\xampp\tmp in your machine and it is read and write allowed